# SSRS (Reporting Services) - Variable values cannotg be used in group expressions

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a tablix with a parent group. In the group properties I am trying to use a report variable within an expression in general tab but I get below error:

```
Variable values cannotg be used in group expressions
```

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: is the variable you're passing in a value in the dataset?

Comment: @newGuy No, it isn't, this variable is defined in the report (rdl) variables. I declared this variable through "Report properties..." and then "Variables" section. For example I declare MaxTablixRowsPerPage = 3

Comment: You will most likely need to add the variable in the "Tablix Group Properties" -> "Variables" tab. This'll be valid within your parent group and child groups. It's evaluated only once.

Comment: @JonathonOgden ok, and once defined there, how I can access this variable from the expression?

Comment: You reference it as with any other variable using `Variables!VariableName.Value`.